# What's wrong with import java.io.*;?

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn how to compile java programs from the command line and I'm getting two errors. Which are bugging me.

DrinkJava.java:

```
import java.oi.*;

public class DrinkJava
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.printIn("Do you like to drink java?");
    }
}
```

Then I run the compiler to try and make the class file:

```
javac DrinkJava.java
```

and I get this error:

```
package java.oi does not exist
```

How do I get that error to go away?

Comment: I don't understand how you managed to type the title without figuring out your error :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's `java.io.*;` and not `java.oi.*;`. Minor spelling mistake. Update `io` instead of `oi`.

Comment: i am not intelligent

Comment: Reading books will make you intelligent.. ;P

Comment: This is a reality check for how much I rely on Intelisense when writing C#... there is no Intelisense for Java in Notepad.

Comment: @quakkels: Maybe it's time to "graduate" to an IDE.  Most Java ones are free...Netbeans, Eclipse, and the community edition of IntelliJ.  Some people advocate learning with a text editor and the command line to start with.  I don't, because one can learn the nitty-gritty later once they have a stronger knowledge of the platform.  When you're just starting out you want help figuring out the easy stuff and you want to be able to explore the language and libraries, and IDEs help a lot with that.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 11):

there is a typo in your code. It is

```
import java.io
```

instead of

```
import java.oi
```

Hope it helps